# How to merge two dictionaries making a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a sample data such as

```
{'Venezuela' : 120, 'Taiwan' : 100, 'New Delhi' : 45 , 'Tokyo' : 600}
```

and I want a list of dictionaries such as

```
[{'value' : 'Venezuela' ,'label' : 120  } , {'value' : 'Taiwan' , 'label' : 100},{'value' :'New Delhi' , 'label':45},{'value':'Tokyo' , 'label' : 600}]
```

Should I segregate the initial dictionaries into key,value dictionaries or is there some other way around it .

Comment: Maybe `[{"value": k, "label": v} for k, v in d.items()]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
x = {'Venezuela' : 120, 'Taiwan' : 100, 'New Delhi' : 45 , 'Tokyo' : 600}

print([{"value":k, "label": v} for k,v in x.items()])
```

Output:

```
[{'label': 120, 'value': 'Venezuela'},
 {'label': 100, 'value': 'Taiwan'},
 {'label': 45, 'value': 'New Delhi'},
 {'label': 600, 'value': 'Tokyo'}]
```

Comment: Makes sense , I am new and a little unaware of list comprehensions. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
our_dict = {
  'Venezuela':120, 
  'Taiwan':100, 
  'New Delhi':45 , 
  'Tokyo':600
  }

def function(d):
  k = []
  for i in d:
    j = {
      'value': i,
      'label': d.get(i)
      }
    k.append(j)
  return k
```

Make sure to add `print(function(our_dict))` to print the result to the console.

Comment: Is there a problem with the code? I got a few downlikes.